# why cos of angle between two vectors is their dot product over product of their length?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I read online that to find angle $\theta$ between two vectors $v=(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $u=(u_1,...,u_n)$, we solve for $\cos(\theta)=\frac{u \text{ dot } v}{\|u\|\|v\|}$. But I don't understand why? why is this formula true?

I understand that the squared norm of a vector $u$ is $\sum_1^n u_i^2$ by the Pythagoras theorem. Would this help prove the result?

Comment: It's from the geometric definition of dot-product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Better link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition

Comment: This question has been asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/846573

Comment: You are also reading the wrong way round: the dot product *is defined* as $u \cdot v = cos(\theta)  ||u|| ||v|| $

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does $cos(x) = \frac{\vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}}{|\vec{v}| \cdot |\vec{w}|}$ make sense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846573/how-does-cosx-frac-vecv-cdot-vecw-vecv-cdot-vecw-make)

Comment: @baibo I think there's a reasonable chance the angle between two vectors is defined this way. For example if I were setting up for differential geometry I'd define angle in terms of dot product, not the other way round. Of course we can't know for sure without a link.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac u{\|u\|}, \frac v{\|v\|}$$ are unit vectors, and WLOG we can take the dot product of the two unit vectors $(1,0)$ and $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, which form an angle of aperture $\alpha$:

$$(1,0)\cdot(\cos\alpha,\sin\theta)=1\cdot\cos\theta+0\cdot\sin\theta=\cos\theta.$$

As the dot product is invariant to a rotation, the dot product is always the cosine of the angle between the vectors.

[image]

Comment: When you define the dot product through coordinates, the crux of the issue is precisely why it is invariant by rotation.

Comment: @Raoul: I know, but I didn't want to clutter the answer with the angle addition formula.

Comment: sorry sir, what if the vectors are in n dimensional instead of 2? how do you generalize?

Comment: Using the same argument, these two vectors can be seen as $n$-dimensional and you can rotate them in $n$-space for generality. $(1,0,0,\cdots0)\cdot(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0,\cdots0)$.